# Search varchar string with comma delimiterin SQL store procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a column (called Check_Regions), in a table in SQL, that is a Varchar with a comma delimiter. I need to write a store procedure that selects all from table where Check_Regions(list) = @Region. How do I search the Check_Regions list to see if it equals the number that's pass to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Region varchar(1024)='US-West'
select Check_Regions from locations 
WHERE SUBSTRING(Check_Regions, PATINDEX('%' + @Region + '%',Check_Regions), LEN(@REGION)) = @Region
```

This is the schema used for testing

```
create table locations
(
loc varchar(1024)

)
insert into locations values ('US-East, US-West, Asia-Pacific')
insert into locations values ('US-East')

declare @Region varchar(1024)='US-West'
select loc  from locations 
WHERE SUBSTRING(LOC, PATINDEX('%' + @Region + '%',LOC), LEN(@REGION)) = @Region
```

Comment: I execute it and it only returns 5 records. And of those records, it's not equaling the numbers together(I.E. I have a in Check_Regions, "0,1,2,3,4,5"; and added a value to @Regions '8', and it returns that same record that doesn't equals. Also, I notice that it returning only the records that have a comma at the end. My data won't have a comma at the end of the least, I corrected that problem, but forgot to reedit the records that already had the comma's at the end(that's how I notice what it was getting, otherwise, it wouldn't return any records). Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: adding the schema also to the answer